# Get all images on Google Maps Details

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

[IONIC 3] [Google place details]
I'm trying to get all the images contained in the "client", until I can display the images in the console, but in html it only displays one, what am I doing wrong?

funcion:

```
photo(place) {
 var photos = place.photos;
 if (!photos) {
  return '';
 }
 for (let i = 0; photos[i]; i++) {
  return '<img src="'+ photos[i].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 2000, 'maxHeight': 1000 }) +'"/>';
  //console.log('<img src="'+ photos[i].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 500, 'maxHeight': 500 }) +'"/>' )
 }
}
```

No HTML:

```
<div id="foto" [innerHTML]="item.photo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return after the loop is complete by concatenating the image tags in to a variable.

```
var images = ''
for (let i = 0; photos[i]; i++) {
  images = images + '<img src="'+ photos[i].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 2000, 'maxHeight': 1000 }) +'"/>';
}
return images;
```

Or you could return the URLs as an array and deal with them at the view part.